# NameError: name 'exponential' is not defined

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal

I am trying to do a raster calculation in the QGIS 3.7 python console, using the following code:

```py
import gdal

bf_thickness = "D:\Minnesota data\Data files\clipped\Buffalo_thickness.tif"

bf_capacity = "D:\Minnesota data\Data files\clipped\Buffalo_capacityPyqgis.tif"

bf_thickness_template = gdal.Open(bf_thickness)

driver_tiff = gdal.GetDriverByName ("GTiff")

bf_capacity_new = driver_tiff.CreateCopy(bf_capacity, bf_thickness_template, strict=0)

band_base_1 = bf_thickness_template.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()

band_new = (band_base_1 * 100 * 30 * 4 * 3.14)/(exponential (0.25 ** 2 * 0.001/(4 * 100 * 30)))

bf_capacity_new.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(band_new)

bf_capacity_new.GetRasterBand(1).ComputeStatistics(0)
```

Here is the error message that I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
NameError: name 'exponential' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is fairly self-explanatory: your code is using a variable called `exponential` that you have not defined. `exponential` is therefore *undefined* and there is no way for your program to know what you want it to do.

For example:

```
a = 5
print(a + b)
```

Would give you the error: `NameError: name 'b' is not defined.` This is because you have defined `a` but not `b`.

Like your program, I'm not sure what you are attempting to do, so I cannot offer a direct alternative. Perhaps if you expand your question to explain the equation you are using then we could offer more advice.

I suspect you might want to use this function: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html, in which case you would add `import numpy` to the top of your script, just after you other `import` statement. Then, instead of `exponential` you would use `numpy.exp`. I suggest spending a bit of time getting comfortable with programming concepts in general, and Python in particular, if this advice is hard to follow.

Comment: How can I define the "exponential" or "logarithmic" function in PyQgis console? Please help a bit more. I am a beginner in programming.

Comment: I've expanded my answer @RaghwendraNarayanShandilya